# Pistons are powered indirectly? Why?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Why are these pistons (indirectly) powered? But the others completely not?
None of them update with a block (Not really a BUD piston I believe, or is it?)

[image]

Comment: defenetly a bud!

Comment: It's not a BUD (Block Update Detector), it doesn't update at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a known concept of [Quasi-Connectivity](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Quasi-connectivity) and may be used as a [Block Update Detector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Block_update_detector) (BUD). Although your specific design does not seem to be BUD.

Relevant quote from the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Quasi-connectivity#Activation_by_quasi-connectivity) (emphasis mine)

> In addition to the normal methods of activation described above, **pistons can also be activated if** one of the methods above **would activate a mechanism component in the block above the piston**, even if there is no mechanism component there (**even if the block above the component is air or a transparent block**).

And some relevant images from the same page

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: aka its the torches fault